# String literals in psql terminal

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I tried to create a table in postgresql and insert some data into that table. However it gives error for my string literals even if I use ' or ".

Please help.

```
sujith=# CREATE TABLE venue (
sujith(#     oid integer NOT NULL,
sujith(#     id integer NOT NULL,
sujith(#     name varchar[30] NOT NULL,
sujith(#     _time_seq_ integer,
sujith(#     _modified_by_ integer,
sujith(#     _modified_on_ timestamp without time zone
sujith(# );
CREATE TABLE
sujith=# INSERT INTO VENUE (oid, id, name) values ( 0 , 1 , 'ibm' );
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "ibm"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO VENUE (oid, id, name) values ( 0 , 1 , 'ibm' );
                                                           ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
sujith=# INSERT INTO VENUE (oid, id, name) values ( 0 , 1 , "ibm" );
ERROR:  column "ibm" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO VENUE (oid, id, name) values ( 0 , 1 , "ibm" );
                                                           ^
sujith=#
```

Comment: `varchar[30]` is an array of `varchar`s, use `varchar(30)` instead; `"ibm"` is not a string literal but identifier with name `ibm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace the `[]` by `()` to solve your issue. So, replace `varchar[30]` by `varchar(30)`

```
CREATE TABLE venue (
oid integer NOT NULL,
 id integer NOT NULL,
name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
_time_seq_ integer,
_modified_by_ integer,
_modified_on_ timestamp without time zone );

INSERT INTO VENUE (oid, id, name) values ( 0 , 1 , 'ibm' );
```